# A-Z categories view

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, web, alphabetical

In my messages board website I want to create a page and within all the forums arranged in alphabetical order. something like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aComposers) does.

it should be dynamic (forums can be created or deleted once in a while).
How do you do that?

Comment: I want to present only the name of each `Forum` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's on controller :

```
@grouped = {}
Forum.all.each do |forum|
  # take and capitalize first character from name
  letter = forum.name.slice(0,1).upcase
  @grouped[letter] ||= [] 
  @grouped[letter] << forum
end
```

Here's on your view :

```
<ul>
  <% @grouped.keys.sort.each do |letter| %>
    <li>
      <h2><%= letter %></h2>
      <ul>
        <% @grouped[letter].each do |forum| %>
          <li><%= forum.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284405/1297435)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful:

```
1.9.3p362 :002 > ["foo", "bar", "baz", "fuzz", "debian"].group_by {|x| x[0] }
=> {"f"=>["foo", "fuzz"], "b"=>["bar", "baz"], "d"=>["debian"]}
```